# How to show document set welcome page in dialog

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Could it be possible to show a document set welcome page (docsethomepage.aspx) inside a model dialog (SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog)?

Have any of you already developed a client side script to change the onclick behaviour of the documentset title-link?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery to remove/unbind the onclick behavior of your document elements and replace them with your own onclick event/implementation which would launch your dialog/page...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` with a calculated field which will contain a hyperlink (using the formula). you will have to compose the document set Url and use it as a property 'URL' in `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`.
FYI,  valid document set url is of the form: [site url]/[doc lib name]/[docset name].
I can explain further if required.